# ES6 for..of in internet explorer 11 produce @@iterator undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, babeljs

I'm working on getting a web-app written with React+Webpack+ES6 that is working on chrome and firefox to work on IE11.
I've track down an issue that I'm using ES6 `for..of` statment which get translated to

```
for (var _iterator = props.mylist[Symbol.iterator](), _step; 
    !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); 
    _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
```

I'm getting `SCRIPT5007: Object expected` which I've tracked down to the fact that props.mylist -> `__proto__` -> `__proto__` has `@@iterator=undefined`.

**UPDATE 1**
Symbol is defined and working in IE as you can see from this screenshot of IE11 dev-tools. This is the JS code produced by webpack.

[image: Symbol OK]

Which polyfill should I use to fix this?

Comment: Can you post you babel config?

Comment: I'll add it but I can tell you I don't have babel-polyfill as it cause out of stack space exception in IE

Comment: You need something to handle Symbol, which `babel-polyfill` does. Other polyfills would likely work too.

Comment: How come I need polyfill for symbol only for ie and not for chrome?